# Once I make an add-on for SAP business one how do I make an install file for it

Tags: sdk, sapb1

I am learning to make add-ons for SAP business one and was wondering how would I compile and make an installation file. We are using version 10 and there is something new I think in how add-ons could be installed.

Comment: I recommend you research the lightweight method. You build a folder and the SDK tool makes it into a .zip and .ard file which you push into SLD.

Comment: Would the answer be on answers.sap.com?

Comment: https://blogs.sap.com/2015/05/22/sap-b1-91-new-add-on-package-and-deployment-tools-extensionpackage-tool-and-extensionmanager/